# Creating addresses on an exchange

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, address, exchange

I have a question, how are addresses for users created on an exchange? As a subaddress or as a new wallet?

If you take an example like LocalMonero, how are the addresses made there?

Answer (score 1):

> how are addresses for users created on an exchange?

An exchange can use many ways to *create* addresses for users. Typically they'll either create subaddresses or integrated addresses using the wallet RPC commands [create_address](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_address) or [make_integrated_address](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address) respectively. Addresses can of course be created without the wallet RPC, in any language, so long as they follow the [correct format](https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/#data-structure).

> If you take an example like LocalMonero, how are the addresses made there?

LocalMonero uses subaddresses for hosted wallets, most likely created using the wallet RPC [create_address](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_address).

Comment: You answered my question very well. Thank you and good luck.